# ADFS Single Logout using Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, adfs

I am new to ADFS SSO and Spring security. I am working on a project which is SSO enabled using ADFS and Spring security. Now my task is to implement Single Logout for this application. Can anyone provide an sample code for obtaining this. It is going to help me a lot. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security can be integrated with ADFS using SAML 2.0 protocol. You can use this [Spring Security SAML extension library](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/) to achieve both Single Sign-on and Single Logout. The extension also includes an integration example in the [sample module](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml).